# Install php-soap in CentOS 5.6 with PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, yum, soap

yum install php-soap

results in "No package php-soap available" warning.  Removing "exclude =php*" from /etc/yum.conf results in confirmation to install php-soap & php-common VERSION 5.1.6-39.el5_8.

I'm afraid to install php components with version 5.1.6* in an OS with php 5.2.17.  Should I be?  Won't earlier 5.1.6* components cause problems with later 5.2.17 php environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the distro supplied php packages. php-soap is a valid package. Seems like you installed php 5.2.x from another repository. Do not use packages from an older version of PHP on a newer one. This will have compatibility issues.

Do a,

```
# yum clean all
# yum search php-soap
# yum install php-soap
```

If the above doesn't work, there are multiple alternatives,

1. Check if the repository where you downloaded php-5.2, has a php-soap package
2. Upgrade to CentOS 6.3 (if this is an option) for later version of php from the distro which is php-5.3.3
3. Stick with CentOS 5.6 and use distro supplied php 5.1 packages
4. There are other 3rd party repositories offering php53 and php54 packages that you may want to try that might have php-soap
5. Compile php by yourself including the php-soap package from source

Comment: Odd that CPanel's autoupdate facility doesn't include php-soap in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to wherever you got the php-5.2 packages and find the matching php-soap package.

Comment: All OS components, including php, were installed as part of automatically recurring CPanel upgrades.  Where do CPanel upgrade packages come from?  What is the command to yum from a specific package and/or add a package without yum?

Comment: The following appears to describe a proper package, but how exactly to use it to install?

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/14957048/dir/redhat_el_5/com/php-soap-5.2.17-1.el5.remi.i386.rpm.html